# Bootstrap Card size different on mobile and desktop

Tags: bootstrap-4, card

I have the Bootstrap Cards (bootstrap4) on my desktop like this:

[image: Desktop]

My mobile view is like this:

[image: Mobile]

My html code is:

```
    <div class="card-deck">
    <div class="center card" style="width: 100%;">
        <a href="{{ path('qrcodemanual') }}"><img id="qrcheck" class="card-img-top" src="{{ asset('images/mobile_qr_code.png') }}"  alt="QR-Code"></a>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{ '/'|trans }}
                {% if qrcodeEnrollStatus == 1 %}
                    <span class="badge badge-success float-right">{{ '/'|trans }} </span>
                {% else %}
                    <span class="badge badge-secondary float-right">{{ '/'|trans }} </span>
                {% endif %}
            </h5>
            <p class="card-text">{{ 'userhome.qrcode.text'|trans }}</p>
            <a href="{{ path('qrcodemanual')}}" class="btn btn-primary">{{ '/'|trans }}</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="center card" style="width: 100%;">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ asset('images/OTP.png') }}" alt="OTP">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{ '/'|trans }}
                {% if smsEnrollStatus != null %}
                    <span class="badge badge-success float-right">{{ '/'|trans }} </span>
                {% else %}
                    <span class="badge badge-secondary float-right">{{ '/'|trans }} </span>
                {% endif %}
            </h5>
            <p class="card-text">{{ '/'|trans }}</p>
            <a href="{{ path('smsmanual')}}" class="btn btn-primary">{{ '/'|trans }}</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<br>
<h5>Other options:</h5>
<br>

<div class="card-deck">
    <div class="center card" style="width: 100%;">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ asset('images/OTP.png') }}" alt="OTP">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{ '/'|trans }}
                {% if emergencyEnrollStatus == 1 %}
                    <span class="badge badge-success float-right">{{ '/' |trans }} </span>
                {% else %}
                    <span class="badge badge-secondary float-right">{{ '/' |trans }} </span>
                {% endif %}
            </h5>
            <p class="card-text">{{ '/'|trans }}</p>
            <a href="{{ path('emergencypasswordmanual')}}" class="btn btn-primary">{{ '/'|trans }}</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="center card" style="width: 100%;">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ asset('images/OTP.png') }}" alt="OTP">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{ '/'|trans }}</h5>
            <p class="card-text">{{ '/'|trans }}</p><br>
            <a href="/" class="btn btn-primary">{{ '/'|trans }}</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the cards in desktop view smaller. How can I do this while keeping my mobile view like it is?

Now when i change the width, the mobile view is also affected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use @media to control some CSS for desktop display only like this:

```
  <style>
      @media  only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
          .card {
            display: block !important;
            width: 25rem !important;
            flex:none !important;
          }
      }
  </style>
```